# What 'appid' should I use with netsh.exe?

Tags: windows, wcf, ssl, netsh

The [netsh](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) command wants an appid ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx)):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

How am I supposed to know the GUID netsh wants me to provide?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use any valid GUID. It is only used to allow you to identify the binding later.

Comment: Later? When is later, like what would you be potentially doing?

Comment: @Tim: You can run "netsh http show sslcert" later and might want to identify which application added what bindings. I don't see much value in the feature, however.

Comment: To create a valid GUID you could use your Visual Studio (Tools -> Create GUID -> Choose "4. Registry Format").

Comment: If you have more applications In one server and each of them add more than one binding. And one day you can migrate one to another server? By GUID you find all bindings assigned to your application. GUID must be for one application the same of course - when you create bindings... :-).

Comment: this does not work for me.  I get the error: SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312
   A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Answer (score 33):

I used the Application GUID for my [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) service that is located within the AsseblyInfo.vb (VB.NET) or AssemblyInfo.cs (C#) file of my hosting application (Windows Service) as shown below:

```csharp
<Assembly: Guid("8fbacae2-bd4e-8ef5-b202-1561845dd04f")>
```

I used this as the appid parameter for the *netsh.exe* tool like so:

```
appid={8fbacae2-bd4e-8ef5-b202-1561845dd04f}
```

It worked perfectly and my WCF service uses HTTPS via that SSL certificate.

Comment: Can you help me setting up HTTPS on WCF?  I have a server and a client and i can't for the life of me get it to work ! :(

Answer (score 9):

If you bind a certificate using the [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) GUI (inetmgr.exe), then perform 'netsh http show sslcert'. You'll see the AppID of {4dc3e181-e14b-4a21-b022-59fc669b0914}, which is the AppID IIS uses, so it's the *appid* I use, too.

Comment: Which is probably not a terribly good idea, since the point of the appid is to differentiate between certificates added by different applications.

Answer (score 5):

"It always says Invalid Argument …"

Try `appid="{7E46BD40-39C6-4813-B414-019AD1122333}"`

with quotes.

See also *["The parameter is incorrect" error using "netsh http add sslcert"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779228/the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-using-netsh-http-add-sslcert)*.