# "The parameter is incorrect" error using "netsh http add sslcert"

Tags: ssl-certificate, netsh

Following the instructions in *[How to: Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx)*, I entered this command on the command line (duh):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport:10.141.146.227:7001 certhash=5d48e604007b867ae8a69260a4ad318d2c05d8ff appid={EDE3C891-306C-40fe-BAD4-895B236A1CC8}
```

Output:

```
The parameter is incorrect.
```

My `certhash` thumbprint was taken from the certificate in *Certificates (Local Computer)* → *Personal* → *Certificates folder*.

The `appid` GUID was generated.

What else is wrong that I need to fix to get this to work?

Comment: Useful info on calling external programs from PowerShell "the right way" here...http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Comment: I realized it was all because of my ORDERING! You gotta put `appid` before `certhash`. Its that dumb.

Comment: For me, the copy-pasted certhash from windows cert manager had some weird character in front - make sure it's just alphanumeric and there is no weird leading chars.

Comment: @JacekGorgoń Yes, me too. Probably a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). 

Comment: In my case, I got the "incorrect parameter" error because I included the `certhash` and `appid` values inside single quotes (`'`). After removing the single quotes, everything succeeded.

Comment: For me it's was characters in uppercase in the fingerprint...

Comment: Where does *"thumbprint"* come from (used in several answers)? Isn't it *[fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint)*? OK, it is used in the supplied Microsoft reference. [Call the whole thing off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRrw2hDjnl4&t=25s)?

Answer (score 107):

In [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell), just type as follows. First get into netsh HTTP mode and then add sslcert. It's worked for me.

```
netsh
```

In the *netsh* session:

```
http

add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:13286 appid='{a5455c78-6489-4e13-b395-47fbdee0e7e6}' certhash=<thumprint without space>
```

Comment: @abdul-hakim I am trying to add an sslcert using netsh http from within a powershell ps1 file, but it keeps throwing errors when I specify a GUID value for the appid.  Here is my code:    $guid = [guid]::NewGuid();     netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$thumb appid={$guid}

Comment: If doing fully on PowerShell command line or a ps1 script remember to quote the curley-braces; else PowerShell will be confused.

Comment: I realized it was all because of my ORDERING! You gotta put `appid` before `certhash`. Its that dumb.

Comment: @Alexandru -- and I had to not only do that but also *remove* the quotes. Yes... dumb is right. :P

Comment: @LarsKemmann - quotes are for powershell, no quotes for command shell - see codingoutlouds answer below

Comment: @Alexandru you do not have to put appid before certhash - it is likely that doing that inadvertently fixed a different issue for you.

Comment: You have to REMOVE all quotes around appid, otherwise you get "The parameter is incorrect".

Comment: I realized the command posted by OP doesn't work in Powershell but works fine in CMD

Answer (score 51):

Another possible cause for this problem is hidden characters being copied from the Certificate Manager page.  If you copy the thumbprint from the details window in Certificates, check for a hidden character at the start (use your arrow keys!).  This was the cause for me of the "The Parameter is Incorrect" error message.

Comment: You're awesome. There is a weird little tick when there is a special character. I noticed it at first but didn't think anything of it. Just removed that special character and SUCCESS. Thanks!

Comment: What hidden character is it? A hex dump will usually reveal an [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) byte sequence (and thus the Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)). One or more Unicode code points can be detected (and search/replaced (deleted)) with regular expressions in most modern text editors, even zero width ones. For example, `\x{00A0}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2212}|\x{00E4}|\x{FFFD}|\x{2217}|\x{200C}|\x{202B}|\x{202A}` to search for the most common ones.

Comment: "200B" is [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779228/the-parameter-is-incorrect-error-using-netsh-http-add-sslcert/39526468#39526468) lists "0x3F 0x38", but it isn't clear if that is the actual byte sequence.

Comment: This invisible left-to-right-mark character has been the source of so much trouble! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp/14852713#14852713 It seems to have been fixed in recent Windows versions and the thumbprint can be copy/pasted without any issues now.

Answer (score 41):

The PowerShell command line and PowerShell scripts in .ps1 files will think curly brackets {...} are PowerShell directives. So quote them. Otherwise, as you have seen, PowerShell will be confused.

So rather than this (which you found fails):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport:10.141.146.227:7001 certhash=5d48e604007b867ae8a69260a4ad318d2c05d8ff appid= {EDE3C891-306C-40fe-BAD4-895B236A1CC8}
```

Do this (note the single quotes):

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport:10.141.146.227:7001 certhash=5d48e604007b867ae8a69260a4ad318d2c05d8ff appid= '{EDE3C891-306C-40fe-BAD4-895B236A1CC8}'
```

Here is some information about PowerShell syntax with curley braces:

*[PowerShell and the hidden art of curly braces and other braces](http://danv74.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/powershell-and-the-hidden-art-of-curly-braces-and-other-braces/)*

Comment: This.  You get the same error in cmd if you don't include the curly braces on the guid, or if you don't quote them in powershell.

Comment: definitely the single quotes in powershell!

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the syntax for the netsh command, I saw this example:

```
add sslcert ipport=1.1.1.1:443 certhash=0102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F1011121314 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

By the looks of it, your problem is that you're doing

```
ipport:10.141.146.227:7001
      ^
```

as opposed to

```
ipport=10.141.146.227:7001
      ^
```

Answer (score 14):

I faced this problem several times and every time it had a different cause. Here are the causes and exact commands that worked for me.

**Here are some causes:**

1. Copy and pasting a certificate thumbprint from the Windows dialog adds a hidden character to your hash. It is not visible in text editors, but you need to remove the character to make it work.
2. An SSL thumbprint should be available in *Personal* → *Certificates* to work with localhost.
3. It should be 'ipport=', not 'ipport:'
4. SSL certificate should have a private key. If you are using the certificate management console, make sure that it has a little key icon on the certificate view.
5. The GUID should be defined in full format: {a10b0420-a21f-45de-a1f8-818b5001145a}, and it should have single quotes in PowerShell: '{a10b0420-a21f-45de-a1f8-818b5001145a}' Thus, the PowerShell format is different from the command line.
6. SSL certificate should have complete characters with all padding '0's and without any space. You may copy the thumbprint (be careful to remove special hidden characters) and remove spaces, or use 'netsh http show sslcert' to get the value if the certificate is already registered for another address.

**What worked for me:**

Here is the exact command that worked for me in PowerShell:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:20001 certhash=5304c034548b27c72b5e9c14f0c7bdd13e52d760 appid='{a10b0420-a21f-45de-a1f8-818b5001145a}'
```

And here is the command line statement:

```
netsh
http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:20001 certhash=5304c034548b27c72b5e9c14f0c7bdd13e52d760 appid={a10b0420-a21f-45de-a1f8-818b5001145a}
```

**More commands to help you avoid related problems:**

Use the following command to see current registered certificate. You may find and reuse certhash or your appid from there:

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

If the certificate is already registered with similar ip and port, you need to remove it. I found it causes a problem with *[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)*, *127.0.0.1* and *0.0.0.0*. You need to have only *0.0.0.0* registered in your testing environment. Use the following command to remove potential corrupted certificates:

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:20001
```

Comment: Re *"thumbprint"*: Do you mean *"[fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen A certificate thumbprint is also called a fingerprint. So, it's same

Answer (score 13):

Copying the certificate thumbprint from the *Certificate\Details\Thumbprint* would prepend the thumbprint value with the bytes '3f38' which, when converted to ANSI were shown as a '?'. This hidden value caused the issue for me.

I pasted the value into [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), chose *Encoding* → *Convert to ANSI*, and then I manually removed the prepended '?' characters. I would then have a *clean* thumbprint value to use.

Comment: 3F38 is both the Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) and [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) byte sequence (UTF-8 0xE3 0xBC 0xB8) for "[CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-3F38](https://codepoints.net/U+3F38)" (㼸), but given the context that is probably not it. 0x3F is itself question mark ("`?`"). A coincidence?

Answer (score 11):

1. Copy the command into [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29)
2. Save it as ANSI
3. Close and reopen the file
4. Remove bogus *?* characters
5. Copy from Notepad to the command prompt and run the command

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error as well when I was just getting started with [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#hypertext-transfer-protocol-stack-httpsys) ([IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)). After I ran:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

then the `netsh http add sslcert` commands started behaving properly.

Comment: This was my issue.

Comment: Seems like this helped me too, even though i've tried a lot of different changes lately, so not sure...

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem is that I am following the Microsoft instructions. I copied the thumbprint from the SSL window. Doing so copies non-printable characters at the beginning of the hash.

Try to paste the thumbprint into [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and then press [<kbd>Home</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key) and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> twice (until the first characters from the thumbprint is deleted) and the readd the character. You can see the character if you copy the thumbprint and paste it into [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

[image: Thumbprint with "?"]

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

My `certhash` parameter wasn't fully 20 bytes long.  I had to pad it with zeroes in front to get it to work.

So, instead of

`certhash=112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00`, I had to do this:

`certhash=00000000112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Serial number instead of the Thumbprint for the certhash parameter will cause this error because of the difference in the amount of characters. Padding with 0s will change the error to:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312

Comment: Does this answer the question (not a rhetorical question)? Perhaps expand your answer to make it clear? (But ************* ***without*** *************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

Watch out. If you have a DNS name as a binding, use *hostnameport* instead of *ipport*:

```
netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport=domainame.com:443
```

I had to delete ADFS Proxy Bindings for [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365) [single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

Answer (score 2):

You have *ipport:* rather than *ipport=* which is easy to do since you follow that with *ip:port*.

Also, watch out for the `{` versus `<` or `(`. That has also gotten me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things I did that I thought made it work after getting the same "The parameter is incorrect." error.

1. I restarted the machine and did it again. It worked the first time.
2. I made sure I was in C:\ and issued the command again after restarting didn't work

   I couldn't explain why, but I think that maybe both times, there was something else wrong. Because the third time this happened to me:
3. I went through the thumbprint of my [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (not the issued server cert) and copied it again from the MMC and it worked.

After this happened, I deleted it again (netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:) and repeated the process using the thumbprint of the server certificate. The darned thing worked again.

I don't know. Just try going through the same thing I did. Maybe one of these would work. In the end, I suspect that I entered a bogus space or character in the certhash.

Answer (score 1):

This will work from the PowerShell command line:

```
$AppId = [Guid]::NewGuid().Guid
$Hash = "209966E2BEDA57E3DB74FD4B1E7266F43EB7B56D"

netsh http add sslcert hostname=localhost:8088 certhash=$Hash appid=`{$AppId`} certstorename my
```

The important details are to escape each { } with a backtick (`) and not to omit *certstorename*. Otherwise, *netsh* raises an error 87.

The variables are just for sake of convenience.

Comment: Thanks for this! In my testing, `ipport=` would work quite happily, but `hostnameport=` would not. Adding `certstore=my` fixed the `hostnameport=` case. Strange! :-)

Comment: Do you mean `$AppId` intead of `$Guid`?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a syntax problem of cmd vs PowerShell. Changing the command to

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8085 certhash=4da5af739d6745de4e38fea9574cdaa79032ea14 appid="{7BBE87B9-D98F-41D7-B726-FC5E1300ED28}"
```

will work in both terminals.

Answer (score 0):

The "-"s are *not* irrelevant.

If your GUID doesn’t look exactly like this, you will get the incorrect parameter error:

{EDE3C891-306C-40fe-BAD4-895B236A1CC8}

vs.

EDE3C891306C40feBAD4895B236A1CC8 -> WRONG 
{EDE3C891306C40feBAD4895B236A1CC8} -> WRONG

Also I’m using the GUID for the appid of [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), not a random one.

Answer (score 0):

I must have ended up mangling the relationship between [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) and [IIS Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#IIS_Express) by deleting the [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) certificate. I was really stuck. The application wouldn't start and nothing I could do seemed to correct this disconnect (which is want brought me to this thread to begin with).

I was finally able to get over the issue by changing the assigned port on the non-SSL URL (`launchSettings.json` in [.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) applications) and disabling the **Enable SSL** checkbox in the project settings and taking a fresh start. I was then able to add my newly created cert with this command: `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44392 appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74b} certhash=A0ADC1A1002F288CCFA96261F9F352D28C675A90`.

Also, note that the `appid` variable is not a reflection of your Visual Studio project AppID (or at least it doesn't have to be). It's just an arbitrary GUID, [according to Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx):

> The AppId doesn't really matter, it's just a GUID. This tells HTTP.SYS that we're using that certificate.

This was not obvious to me and made dealing with the **parameter is incorrect** error that much more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add an [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and port with the hostnameport parameter, so I got this parameter error.

`netsh http add sslcert hostnameport="10.0.0.120:443"`

Instead of:

`netsh http add sslcert ipport="10.0.0.120:443"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a hidden issue that only showed in PowerShell, not on a command prompt.

I had copied a thumbprint from a certificate and removed all spaces in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), but it still had a hidden character in front.

It looked like this:

.. certhash=dca41243...

It was actually

.. certhash="special char"dca41243...

Answer (score 0):

We have put the **parameters in quotes** (double quotes, not single), and this helped us. This way it worked perfectly.

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport="servername.domain.suffix:8443" certhash="6a1234abcd567edf" appid="{eca1234-a456-5678-abcd-edffg6789}" certstorename="MY"
```