# Using Port 443 for SSL when developing MVC4 site under VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have followed instructions online to be able to use IISExpress on ports 80 and 443. However, when I try to set the Enable SSL property on an MVC4 site in VS2012, it always assigns port 44300. That assignment cannot be edited in the VS2012 property window.

What's odd is that the config file for IISExpress is set to only bind ports 80 and 443 (I deleted the bindings for localhost, which included one for port 44300).

Anyone know how to get VS2012 to use port 443 when IISExpress is set up to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690901/iis-express-defaulting-to-port-44300-for-https-when-enabling-ssl

Comment: I read that question before posting my own. What's different is the other poster wants to know how to set up SSL on IISExpress. I've already done that. What I want to know is how to get VS2012 to stop trying to use port 44300 when I enable SSL in the project properties for my MVC app. Somehow, VS2012 isn't recognizing the IISExpress configuration information.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a parameter in the project file (e.g., YourApp.csproj, if you're using C#) which sets the SSL port to use. I couldn't find a way to change this from within the VS2012 UI. But if you modify the csproj file in Notepad -- the parameter name is IISExpressSSLPort -- then when you select SSL Enabled in VS2012 it'll use port 443. It will also not overwrite the setting in the IISExpress config file, too, which is also useful :)