# Change https to different port IIS Express applicationhost.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-express

I start two websites in a sln of mine. Because the https port 44300 is used for both websites, the startup of the second website fails with IISExpress error.

If I change the HTTPS port in the applicationhost.config for one of the sites it just gets reverted back to 44300. I deleted the https binding entries, they just get added back.

```
      <site name="prj(1)" id="130">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="PATH" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:53884:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
       <site name="prj2" id="102">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="PATH" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54777:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this thread on SO:
[IIS Express defaulting to port 44300 for https when enabling SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690901/iis-express-defaulting-to-port-44300-for-https-when-enabling-ssl)

The binding:

```
 <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
```

will always get added to the IIS Express applicationhost.config sooner or later, no matter how many times you try to remove it.

From my link though, there is mention of "the port 44300 is sequential: 00 mean that its the first application you have configured as SSL enabled; 01 will be the second one and so on."

So I just changed my bindings to F5 multiple websites, using IIS Express at the same time to:

Website1:

Website2:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:localhost" />
```