# Forcing SSL on port 443 in IIS Express for an MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-express

I have an MVC 5 web application parts of which I need to run using SSL (lie login, account management etc). I enabled SSL for the web project, changed bindings in `applicationhost.config`:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:example.com" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:example.com" />
</bindings>
```

But, when I restart IIS Express and run the site, it overwrites the SSL port to 44300. Any ideas to make it stay at 443?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `netsh http show sslcert`. In the output search for entry for `port 44300` and copy the `certhash` and `appID` values.
2. Delete the entry for 44300: `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44300`
3. Add a new entry for port 443 with certhash and appID from step 1: `netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=<certhash> appid=<appid>`.

If you're running this inside Powershell, you'll need to wrap the parameters in single quotes, so the command in step 3 above becomes `netsh http add sslcert 'ipport=0.0.0.0:443' 'certhash=<certhash>' 'appid=<appid>'`

After configuring the entry in http.sys, you need to restart http service for the changes to take effect.

```bash
net stop http
net start http
```

From Powershell, you can restart the service like this:

```bash
Restart-Service http
```

Comment: I tried that, changed the cert to port 443 successfully (ran `etsh http show sslcert` to make sure port 443 shows up), then changed https binding to port 443. But when I open my web project in VS it forces the binding to change to 44300 again

Comment: Ok, i also opened the csproj file, changed the port there and now it seems to work ok

Comment: Great that you figured it out!

Comment: Fo anyone trying this, if you see "The parameter is incorrect" when adding certificate, instead type netsh then enter, then inside netsh enter remaining part of the command.

Comment: @Vitaly - the "Parameter is Incorrect" message is returned from Powershell, and simply indicates you need to wrap the parameters in single quotes; so `netsh http add sslcert 'ipport=0.0.0.0:443'`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have mapped proper bindings. enable your application to use `https` in IIS by right click on webapplication virtual directory -> manage Application -> advance setting -> Enable Protocols

[image]

In FeaturedView pane click `SSL Settings` and check the box says `Require SSL` and click Apply.

[image]

You may also want to look at this existing post [IIS Express defaulting to port 44300 for https when enabling SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690901/iis-express-defaulting-to-port-44300-for-https-when-enabling-ssl?rq=1)

Comment: Rahul - what you described is for IIS, not IIS Express

Comment: @Andrey, Ahh! I see that now. But can you not switch to IIS.