# Why String.Equals is returning false?

Tags: c#, string, comparison, equality

I have the following C# code (from a library I'm using) that tries to find a certificate comparing the thumbprint. Notice that in the following code both `mycert.Thumbprint` and `certificateThumbprint` are strings.

```
var certificateThumbprint = AppSettings.CertificateThumbprint;

var cert =
    myStore.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(
      mycert => 
      mycert.Thumbprint != null && mycert.Thumbprint.Equals(certificateThumbprint)
      );
```

This fails to find the certificate with the thumbprint because `mycert.Thumbprint.Equals(certificateThumbprint)` is `false` even when the strings are equal. `mycert.Thumbprint == certificateThumbprint` also returns `false`, while `mycert.Thumbprint.CompareTo(certificateThumbprint)` returns 0.

[image]

I might be missing something obvious, but I can't figure out why the `Equals` method is failing. Ideas?

Comment: This might be a strange question... but are the Lengths the same on each string? (trying to see if there are any non-printable characters in there somehow).

Comment: From the [`string.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx) docs: *Character sets **include ignorable characters.** The CompareTo method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison. For example, if the following code is run on the .NET Framework 4 or later, a comparison of "animal" with "ani-mal" (using a soft hyphen, or U+00AD) indicates that the two strings are equivalent.*

Comment: @Yuval Your citation seems to imply the opposite of what vcsjones is suspecting.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My citation indicates that `CompareTo` excludes ignorable charecters from the comparison. That is why `CompareTo` returns 0. I think that's what vcsjones ment.

Comment: First do what @vcsjones suggests.  If everything checks out, try normalizing both operands, e.g, something akin to `string.Equals(mycert.Thumbprint != null ? mycert.Thumbprint.Normalize() : null, certificateThumbprint.Normalize())`.

Comment: Can you give short example that reproduct the same problem? That we can test ofc.

Comment: I suggest for troubleshooting: Loop through the strings and do a char by char comparison.

Comment: Please look at the `.ToCharArray()` of each string and compare them character-by-character. There is almost certainly a subtle character difference. If the strings are reporting: *the strings probably aren't equal*

Comment: Is this a LINQ to SQL/Entity Framework query?

Comment: Not the problem, but if you're using `FirstOrDefault`, you should be checking `myCert` for null in addition to `myCert.Thumbprint`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie His delegate is the predicate that gets passed to `FirstOrDefault()`; it's not operating on the result.  The input sequence cannot contain any null elements due to the presence of the `OfType()` operator.  The result (`cert`) might be null, but not `myCert`.

Comment: Did you copy paste the cert thumbprint into your AppSettings? See [How to find certificate by its thumbprint in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @MikeStrobel yeah, that's true :$

Comment: The Thumbprint is hex-encoded binary data, there should be no ignorable/unprintable characters in it.

Comment: @PeterRitchie the first line of code reads `var certificateThumbprint = AppSettings.CertificateThumbprint;`, hence my question. Problem is explained [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp). And don't you love hit'n'run-questions, OP wasn't seen for an hour already.

Comment: Could be a compiler issue? Maybe the "equals" is not the method of the string but of the object

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers. It was indeed a problem with the string from the app settings. It started with two characters 8206 (or U+2000E, i.e. left-to-right-mark). I have fixed that and everything worked.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CompareTo ignores certain characters:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = "asdas"+(char)847;//add a hidden character
    var b = "asdas";
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); //false
    Console.WriteLine(a.CompareTo(b)); //0
    Console.WriteLine(a.Length); //6
    Console.WriteLine(b.Length); //5

   //watch window shows both a and b as "asdas"
}
```

(Here, the character added to `a` is `U+034F`, Combining Grapheme Joiner.)

[image: Debug mode]

So CompareTo's result is not a good indicator of a bug in Equals. The most likely reason of your problem is hidden characters. You can check the lengths to be sure.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Indeed, I was having two U+200E (left-to-right mark) characters at the beginning of the `certificateThumbprint` string. Removing that fixed the problem.

Comment: Of all the answers this is the correct one. There are also comments that also indicated the correct problem, including linking to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp. I will mark this as the accepted answer. Wish I could also do that for comments.

Comment: has this exact case as a result of &nbsp was stored in a string in the database but was only showing as a space, was able to see the unicode chars when pasted into sublime text fkn unicode encodings can be such a nuisance sometimes lol

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to try using an overload of `String.Equals` that accepts a parameter of type `StringComparison`. 

*For example:*

```
myCert.Thumbprint.Equals(certificateThumbprint, StringComparison.[SomeEnumeration])
```

Where `[SomeEnumeration]` is replaced with one of the following enumerated constants:

```
 - CurrentCulture
 - CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
 - InvariantCulture
 - InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
 - Ordinal
 - OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Reference the MSDN Documentation found **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)**.
[image]

Comment: I tried with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` and the result was the same (i.e. false).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we insert data in database it stores some spaces like **"question  "**. And when you will try to compare it with **"question"** it returns false. So my suggestion is: please check the value in database or use Trim() method.

In your case, please try:
    *mycert.Thumbprint != null && mycert.Thumbprint.trim().equals(certificateThumbprint.trim())*

I think it will return true if any record will exist.