# Simple if between two strings fails

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue with a simple IF statement:

```
string a = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
Debug.Log(a);
if (a == "test")
   GameObject.Find("PracticeButton").GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
```

The expression evaluates as false even thou i can clearly see that the values are the same. [image: right and left side are equal]

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?
I've tried String.Equals but have the same result.

Comment: you might have a hidden character in that string. like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25999691/5174469). Try to compare `a.Length == "test".Length` what does this return?

Comment: the post suggests to use the `CompareTo` method. It would ignore hidden characters

Comment: Variable a seems to have 5 characters compared to 4.

Comment: While @MongZhu comment seems to be the solution, I do suggest you delete the text in the `TextMeshProUGUI` and retype it again. If possible, copy the "test" from the `if` statement and paste it to the `TextMeshProUGUI`.

Comment: I cannot tell you how it got in, but if the answer from the post helps you I will mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: yes thank you, i'll have to investigate why TextMeshPro adds a character