# Find X509 certificate from store based on Thumbprint

Tags: c#, ssl

I am trying to find a certificate from store using its Thumbprint. I am having very hard time to find what is the problem with my code. [image: See the image]

Top section shows my code with debugger stopped at that position. Then I have copied that statement into Immediate Window and the count is zero.

There are two certificates in the location that I am trying to find and second certificate is what i am interested in. So I have modified the statement to use the thumbprint of that certificate rather than typing it manually in. Now the count is 1.

Then I just printed Thumbprint and copied to previous statement and count is 1. So I thought there is a typo. but I you see the last two statements, there is no typo. only difference is spaces, which does not matter. But I tried making both statements look exactly same but result always differ.

Not sure what is going on... either i am missing very simple thing or i am too stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original string might contain invisible Unicode characters. If the thumbprint string from `Certificate[1].Thumbprint` works fine, copy it from debug window and use that one instead.

Comment: i have this problem again. Previously i was able to solve it by copying from debugger but I cannot do that for prod deployment. Copying the thumbprint to notepad also did not help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: this one helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp