# X509Store.Certificates.Find( FindBySerialNumber ) not matching

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Before I begin, this is not a duplicate of this QA ( [How to find certificate by its thumbprint in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp) ) - the thumbprint string I'm using is 40 characters long and does not contain any hidden characters copied from MMC.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
String thumbprint = "c112345678904655585e8c8244af5d3f2630498b".ToUpperInvariant();
assert( thumbprint.Length == 40 );

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection matches = store.Certificates.Find(X509.FindType.FindBySerialNumber, thumbprint, validOnly: false );
assert( matches.Count == 1 ); // this fails, the count is == 0.
```

But when I interrogate the certificates manually, it's fine:

```
assert( store.Certificates.Count == 1 ); // there is only 1 cert in the store
X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates[0];

assert( cert.Thumbprint == thumbprint ); // this passes
```

What could cause this? Why would `Find` not return a certificate when there's an exact match?

This MSDN Blog post describes the same, though provides no explanation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2011/11/19/what-to-do-when-your-code-could-not-find-the-certificate-in-azure-vm/

Comment: .Find(X509.FindType.FindBy**SerialNumber**, **thumbprint**, validOnly: false ); http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35691/what-is-the-difference-between-serial-number-and-thumbprint

Comment: @Rob Derp! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `X509.FindType.FindBySerialNumber` instead of `X509.FindType.FindByThumbprint` without realizing it. It's working now.