# Find a particular SSL certificate on IIS

Tags: c#, ssl, iis

i have purcahsed and installed a SSL certificate from a CA. Now I want to

1. Get the certificates private key in a c# program to decrypt incoming message.

How do I programmatically access the exact certificate installed on my web server. There seem to be many installed there.

Comment: Threads like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115511/how-to-find-certificate-by-its-thumbprint-in-c-sharp already cover that.

Answer (score 0):

This code does it. I was stuck at what exact attribute to use for the search. 'Subject' workd just fine.

https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/using-self-signed-certificates-to-encrypt-text.html