# Self-hosting using SSL and WCF - can't bind certificate to port

Tags: wcf, ssl

I have a WCF service that I want to access using SSL. I'm on my developer machine, so I was thinking of self-hosting the service. I've been following *[Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)*.

I've created a self-signed certificate which I added to the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*. I've created another two certificates signed by the first one, one for the client and the other for the server. I followed *[Using makecert to create certificates for development](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development.)*.

I can't get past the SSL certificates configuration step. When I'm binding the certificate to the port number using [netsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netsh) it throws an SSL error:

> Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Does the certificate need some special field or some other thing for this to work?

[CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) certificate:

```
makecert -n "CN=TestCA" -cy authority -a sha1 -sv "TestCA.pvk" -r "TEST_CA.cer"
```

Service certificate:

```
makecert -n "CN=rneapp.com" -ic "TEST_CA.cer"  -iv "TestCA.pvk" -a sha1 -sky exchange -pe -sv "rneapp.com.pvk" "rneapp.com.cer"
```

Client certificate:

```
makecert -n "CN=rneClient" -ic "TEST_CA.cer"  -iv "TestCA.pvk" -a sha1 -sky exchange -pe -sv "rneClient.pvk" "rneClient.cer"
```

I'm using this command to bind the certificate to the port:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8465 certhash=a853f3b5b48b8a506bdc4212ba2726a3bfea2bb6 appid={2E53B9B0-17AE-4EBC-A1AE-43D53A6FD07D} clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

Comment: How did you determine the appid for the last command?

Comment: I generated the a GUID for the appid.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537173/what-appid-should-i-use-with-netsh-exe

Comment: You should be able to get the appid from the AssemblyInfo.cs/vb file

Comment: I had a recent run-in with this issue. I solved my problem as follow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19766650/481656

Answer (score 7):

When I encountered the same issue, moving the certificate from Current User to Local Computer storage helped, so try checking your certificate storage.

Built-in help for `netsh http add sslcert` also mentions this with regard to `certstorename` option:

```
        certstorename           - Store name for the certificate. Defaults
                                  to MY. Certificate must be stored in the
                                  local machine context.
```

Comment: +1, This worked perfect. I was storing the cert from code and just had to change, new X509Store(StoreName.My) to new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

Answer (score 1):

I also run into similar error code through different process of creating the self-signed certificate and find the source of my own problem. [Using netsh, bind an SSL certificate to a port number is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641723/netsh-bind-ssl-certificate-to-port-number-failing/9642626#9642626)

[Here is the article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service) I follow to create the self-signed certificate and it is quite complete and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 but for me it is working the first time I bind the certificate with the port. However if I delete the binding (netsh.exe http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9101) and bind again with the same certificate, it fails. If I try another port, it fails. If I create a brand new certificate then I can bind again. But again deleting/binding will fail.

I follow the same rules as this question: 
[Can't register a C# generated selfsigned SSL certificate with netsh (error 1312)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729623/can-register-a-c-sharp-generated-selfsigned-ssl-cert-with-netsh-error-1312)

I also tried to install KB981506 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981506 but it failed to install "The update is not applicable to your computer". Maybe I have it already.

I have a feeling something is not deleted in a right way when the binding is deleted. ProcessMonitor doesn't show any thing weird when I try to bind again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue. [Check out this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;981506&sd=rss&spid=14134).

You may also be setting up the certificates incorrectly. [Check out this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/8ca6b41a-3afa-4f3d-a191-ddce842314e1) for how another person was making a similar mistake and getting the 1312 error which was just distracting him from the real problem which was his certificate configuration.

Comment: That hotfix only aplies to Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, I'm using Windows Vista. : \

Comment: Added some more detail about potentially setting up the certs incorrectly. It would be more helpful if, instead of linking to articles that you used, you posted the exact makecert options you used in generating your keys so we can make sure that you've actually chosen the right options.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Posted the exact commands I'm using to generate the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, and this is how I fixed it. When I have watched certificates installed on my local computer/my in mmc.exe, I have seen that my certificate haven't icon with key.

So when I combine *.cer and *.pvk file to *.pfx with:

```
pvk2pfx -pvk "private_key.pvk"  -spc "public.cert" -pfx "test.pfx"
```

And then import *.pfx file with mmc.exe.

Then the next commands will execute with no errors:

```
netsh http add sslcert...
netsh http delete sslcert...
```

I have posted this answer to similar Stack Overflow question, *[Can't register a C# generated selfsigned SSL certificate with netsh (error 1312)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729623/can-register-a-c-sharp-generated-selfsigned-ssl-cert-with-netsh-error-1312/21075075#21075075)*.