# netsh binding imported ssl certificate to port

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, bind, wcf-binding, netsh

I've created an authority certificate and client certificate (that is signed by the first one). What I'm trying to do is to import both certificates (which I think I do with success) and then bind client certificate to port using this netsh command :

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=xxx appid={xxx}
```

When I create this certificates and use the command above it's done correctly. But I have to do remove/import certificates operation and in this case it fails.

I've done some search and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641723/netsh-bind-ssl-certificate-to-port-number-failing) that maybe I have to "delete this certificate properly* from your certificate store and IIS Server cache" (by Johnydep). I don't use IIS Server (it's a self-hosted wcf service) so - have you got any ideas what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :
According to the issue-trace [here](http://www.kozeniauskas.com/itblog/2011/03/25/ssl-certificate-add-failed-error-1312/) ( "the certificate that you are using does not have the private key" ) I've just tried creating the authority certificate with private key in the same file but with no effect.