# Self-hosted OWIN .NET 4.5 Web API 2 does not work with Windows authentication and https

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am trying to get Web API 2 to work with Windows authentication and SSL. It looks like it can work with either one or the other, but when I enable both Windows authentication and SSL, I keep getting 401 responses from the server.

This is how we enable Windows authentication:

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

When running with just HTTP (no HTTPS), Windows authentication seems to work. I see 401 responses followed by a 200 response.

I am also trying to get it to work with HTTPS on my local machine.

I went through the following steps to enable HTTPS:

- Added a mapping to the server name in my hosts file
- Installed a certificate (with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368004/2274701))
- Reserved a URL (`https://+:10001/`)
- Ran the service under the reserved URL

Starting the service:

```
var startOptions = new StartOptions();
startOptions.Urls.Add(baseUrl); // baseUrl is "https://+:10001/"
_webApplication = WebApp.Start<Startup>(startOptions);
```

If I disable Windows authentication (comment out the 2 lines with `HttpListener` above), I can access the service using the HTTPS protocol. The browser recognizes the certificate.

When I enable Windows authentication, I keep getting 401 responses (in Fiddler I can see up to 6 401 responses for one request). A browser keeps prompting me to log in, and fails after a number of attempts with a 401 code.

I have been trying to find someone facing a similar problem. [This post](https://frendsrnd.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/httpselfhostserver-hosted-web-api-with-https-and-windows-authentication-enabled/) looked promising. However, the author did not seem to have any issues with the .NET 4.5 version of OWIN.

Could anyone please advise? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our problem was the authentication rather than SSL.

- Using `AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm` helped
- The other problem was the correct registration of the server name within the organization, so that clients (developers' machines) could access it