# Bouncy Castle's X509V3CertificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm marked obsolete. What do I do?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I am trying to create a self-signed trusted certificate. I am using Bouncy Castle from nuget, and the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230745/generate-self-signed-certificate-on-the-fly). This is the code on that page:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(string subjectName, string issuerName, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey,  int keyStrength = 2048)
{
// Generating Random Numbers
var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

// The Certificate Generator
var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

// Serial Number
var serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

// Signature Algorithm
const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

// Issuer and Subject Name
var subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
var issuerDN = issuerName;
certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

// Valid For
var notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

// Subject Public Key
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

// Generating the Certificate
var issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

// selfsign certificate
var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerPrivKey, random);

// correcponding private key
PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);


// merge into X509Certificate2
var x509 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

var seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.PrivateKey.GetDerEncoded());
if (seq.Count != 9)
    throw new PemException("malformed sequence in RSA private key");

var rsa = new RsaPrivateKeyStructure(seq);
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
    rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

x509.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
return x509;
}


public static AsymmetricKeyParameter GenerateCACertificate(string subjectName, int keyStrength = 2048)
{
// Generating Random Numbers
var randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
var random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

// The Certificate Generator
var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

// Serial Number
var serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

// Signature Algorithm
const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

// Issuer and Subject Name
var subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
var issuerDN = subjectDN;
certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

// Valid For
var notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

// Subject Public Key
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

// Generating the Certificate
var issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

// selfsign certificate
var certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(issuerKeyPair.Private, random);
var x509 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());
// Add CA certificate to Root store
addCertToStore(cert, StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

return issuerKeyPair.Private;
}
```

So far, so good, but the "SetSignatureAlgorithm" and "Generate" methods are marked as obsolete. Intellisense suggests using an "ISignatureFactory", and that's where I got lost. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
static void Main()
{
    //Console.WriteLine(ExecuteCommand("netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443"));
    var applicationId = ((GuidAttribute)typeof(Program).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value;
    var certSubjectName = "TEST";
    var sslCert = ExecuteCommand("netsh http show sslcert 0.0.0.0:4443");
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (sslCert.IndexOf(applicationId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This implies we can start running.");
        Console.WriteLine(ExecuteCommand("netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443"));
        //store.Remove(certs.First(x => x.Subject.Contains(certSubjectName)));
    }

    AsymmetricKeyParameter myCAprivateKey = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Creating CA");
    X509Certificate2 certificateAuthorityCertificate = CreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate("CN=" + certSubjectName + "CA", ref myCAprivateKey);
    Console.WriteLine("Adding CA to Store");
    AddCertificateToSpecifiedStore(certificateAuthorityCertificate, StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    Console.WriteLine("Creating certificate based on CA");
    X509Certificate2 certificate = CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnCertificateAuthorityPrivateKey("CN=" + certSubjectName, "CN=" + certSubjectName + "CA", myCAprivateKey);
    Console.WriteLine("Adding certificate to Store");
    AddCertificateToSpecifiedStore(certificate, StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    Console.WriteLine(ExecuteCommand($"netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443 certhash={certificate.Thumbprint} appid={{{applicationId}}}"));

    // Check to see if our cert exists
    // If the cert does not exist create it then bind it to the port
    // If the cert does exist then check the port it is bound to
    // If the port and thumbprint match and applicationId match continue
    // Else throw exception
    // See here for more netsh commands https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791(v=vs.110).aspx
}

public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnCertificateAuthorityPrivateKey(string subjectName, string issuerName, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey)
{
    const int keyStrength = 2048;

    // Generating Random Numbers
    CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerPrivKey, random);
    // The Certificate Generator
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage((new ArrayList() { new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") })));

    // Serial Number
    BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
    certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

    // Signature Algorithm
    //const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA512WITHRSA";
    //certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

    // Issuer and Subject Name
    X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
    X509Name issuerDN = new X509Name(issuerName);
    certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
    certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

    // Valid For
    DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

    certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

    // Subject Public Key
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
    var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
    var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

    certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

    // Generating the Certificate
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;

    // selfsign certificate
    X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

    // correcponding private key
    PrivateKeyInfo info = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(subjectKeyPair.Private);


    // merge into X509Certificate2
    X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

    Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(info.ParsePrivateKey().GetDerEncoded());
    if (seq.Count != 9)
    {
        //throw new PemException("malformed sequence in RSA private key");
    }

    RsaPrivateKeyStructure rsa = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(seq); //new RsaPrivateKeyStructure(seq);
    RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters rsaparams = new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        rsa.Modulus, rsa.PublicExponent, rsa.PrivateExponent, rsa.Prime1, rsa.Prime2, rsa.Exponent1, rsa.Exponent2, rsa.Coefficient);

    x509.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(rsaparams);
    return x509;

}
public static X509Certificate2 CreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate(string subjectName, ref AsymmetricKeyParameter CaPrivateKey)
{
    const int keyStrength = 2048;

    // Generating Random Numbers
    CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

    // The Certificate Generator
    X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    // Serial Number
    BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
    certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

    // Signature Algorithm
    //const string signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
    //certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

    // Issuer and Subject Name
    X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name(subjectName);
    X509Name issuerDN = subjectDN;
    certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
    certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

    // Valid For
    DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

    certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
    certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

    // Subject Public Key
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
    KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
    RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

    certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

    // Generating the Certificate
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;
    ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);
    // selfsign certificate
    X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
    X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());

    CaPrivateKey = issuerKeyPair.Private;

    return x509;
    //return issuerKeyPair.Private;

}
public static bool AddCertificateToSpecifiedStore(X509Certificate2 cert, StoreName st, StoreLocation sl)
{
    bool bRet = false;

    try
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(st, sl);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(cert);

        store.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured");
    }

    return bRet;
}
public static string ExecuteCommand(string action)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            Arguments = "/c " + action
        }
    })
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing Command:");
        Console.WriteLine(action);
        process.Start();
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
        process.Close();
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Here is a more complete answer. This gets rid of all the obsolete calls in both methods.

Note - I was using the NuGet Install-Package BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed a complete answer. However, the AddExtension() method of X509V3CertificateGenerator class is also marked as obsolete. The overloaded method expecting an IEnumerable is not. So I changed that line to:
`certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(new List<DerObjectIdentifier() { new DerObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }));`

Comment: Here is an even better method of doing that as well.            certificateGenerator.AddExtension(
                X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id,
                true,
                new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth));

Comment: @Lourens 

Finally figured out all the OID codes.
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 - id_kp_serverAuth 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 - id_kp_clientAuth 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 - id_kp_codeSigning 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 - id_kp_emailProtection 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.5 - id-kp-ipsecEndSystem 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6 - id-kp-ipsecTunnel 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7 - id-kp-ipsecUser 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8 - id_kp_timeStamping 
         1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.9 - OCSPSigning

Answer (score 10):

To make IdahoSixString's excellent answer more complete:
The above code will not work in the part where it tries to bind the certificate to the program and port:

```
('netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443 certhash={certificate.Thumbprint} appid={{{applicationId}}}'). At least not in .NET4.5.
```

You will get the error:

> "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 
>   A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

This is apparently because the private key does not persist when the corresponding RSA object is closed. So I followed the advise in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419911/cannot-export-generated-certificate-with-private-key-to-byte-array-in-net-4-0-4), and the following code works for me:

```
public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnCertificateAuthorityPrivateKey(string subjectName, string issuerName, AsymmetricKeyParameter issuerPrivKey)
    {
        const int keyStrength = 2048;

        // Generating Random Numbers
        CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerPrivKey, random);

        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id, true, new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth));

        // Serial Number
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=" + subjectName);
        X509Name issuerDN = new X509Name("CN=" + issuerName);
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
        var keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
        var keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        // selfsign certificate
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);
        var dotNetPrivateKey = ToDotNetKey((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)subjectKeyPair.Private);

        // merge into X509Certificate2
        X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(certificate));
        x509.PrivateKey = dotNetPrivateKey;
        x509.FriendlyName = subjectName;

        return x509;
    }

    public static X509Certificate2 CreateCertificateAuthorityCertificate(string subjectName, out AsymmetricKeyParameter CaPrivateKey)
    {
        const int keyStrength = 2048;

        // Generating Random Numbers
        CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

        // The Certificate Generator
        X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        // Serial Number
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigIntegers.CreateRandomInRange(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.ValueOf(Int64.MaxValue), random);
        certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        // Issuer and Subject Name
        X509Name subjectDN = new X509Name("CN=" + subjectName);
        X509Name issuerDN = subjectDN;
        certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(issuerDN);
        certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(subjectDN);

        // Valid For
        DateTime notBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        DateTime notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(2);

        certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(notBefore);
        certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(notAfter);

        // Subject Public Key
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair subjectKeyPair;
        KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(random, keyStrength);
        RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
        subjectKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(subjectKeyPair.Public);

        // Generating the Certificate
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair issuerKeyPair = subjectKeyPair;
        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA512WITHRSA", issuerKeyPair.Private, random);

        // selfsign certificate
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = certificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

        X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificate.GetEncoded());
        x509.FriendlyName = subjectName;

        CaPrivateKey = issuerKeyPair.Private;

        return x509;
    }

    public static AsymmetricAlgorithm ToDotNetKey(RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey)
    {
        var cspParams = new CspParameters()
        {
            KeyContainerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Exchange,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
        };

        var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
        var parameters = new RSAParameters()
        {
            Modulus = privateKey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            P = privateKey.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q = privateKey.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            DP = privateKey.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            DQ = privateKey.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            InverseQ = privateKey.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            D = privateKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Exponent = privateKey.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
        };

        rsaProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);
        return rsaProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Do we know when or how the RSA object is closed?

Comment: @lourens Thanks bud for your COMPLETE solution, I was going bald over the 1312 error for the past 2 days...!

Comment: @lourens, ok, close but no cigar... I get "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost:4444'."  when testing the ssl connection to my service that uses this cert... did you solve that too? (also the Enhanced Key Usage property shows with a warning exclamation mark in the certificate mmc.)

Comment: @zukanta: I always see an excamation mark in every certificate that has an Enhanced Key Usage field. Also: did you make the subject of your derived certificate "localhost", or something else? You must use the exact subject name when navigating to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the code of Lourens I couldn't get it to work and the certificate wouldn't be accepted by chrome.
I had to add in the CreateSelfSignedCertificateBasedOnCertificateAuthorityPrivateKey the following code to get it working.

```
       // Subject Alternative Name 
        var alternativeNames = subjectAlternativeNames.Select(n => new GeneralName(GeneralName.DnsName, n)).ToArray<Asn1Encodable>();
        var subjectAlternativeNamesExtension = new DerSequence(alternativeNames);
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName.Id, false, subjectAlternativeNamesExtension);

        //Key Usage
        certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.KeyEncipherment));
```

By the way changed also the following line

```
certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage.Id, false, new ExtendedKeyUsage( new [] { KeyPurposeID.IdKPClientAuth, KeyPurposeID.IdKPServerAuth}));
```