# How to run a Gist by embedding in a web page or by powershell to solve ssl certificate error?

Tags: powershell, ssl, embed, iis-express, gist

I am developing a web site in Visual Studio 2013 using IISExpress and have enabled HTTPS creating a certificate thru Visual Studio. This has a known problem when running in Chrome as documented here [VS 2017: All new/existing HTTPS web sites give a certificate error in Chrome](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52422/vs-2017-all-newexisting-https-web-sites-give-a-cer.html).

The solution there uses a gist from here [camieleggermont/UpdateIISExpressCertificate.ps1](https://gist.github.com/camieleggermont/5b2971a96e80a658863106b21c479988)  to generate a new certificate and have it replace the old one.

I've tried running that but with no success.

I tried embedding the code in my page. I placed this code `<script src="https://gist.github.com/camieleggermont/5b2971a96e80a658863106b21c479988.js"></script>` in the `html` `head` tag like style links and `meta` tags.

When running I see the gist code in the background of the page and I still get the certificate error.

I tried putting that `script` tag in other places on the page with the same results.

What should I do to embed this and get it to run? Or how do I run it as a powershell command?

Also is there another alternative to solve the certificate problem in Chrome?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to run the script in powershell on your machine, not embed it into the website

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen How do I do that?

Comment: I found the solution for the Certificate problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676993/how-do-i-change-my-iis-express-ssl-certificate-for-one-that-will-work-with-chrom?rq=1 in Chris's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use Jexus Manager (free and open source) to generate a self-signed certificate,

- SHA256.
- CN and SAN are set to the value you want.

Thus, it matches Chrome's requirements. Also you can easily add the certificate to trusted root in it,

https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0

Comment: Thank you Lex Li. I just saw your solution in the Visual Studio Community post on this subject. I understand that Jexus Manager is commercial and has to be bought. Is that correct?

Comment: @DovMiller nope. It is free and open source.