# How to solve this issue whlie run .net core web application

Tags: visual-studio-2019

**I m working with visual studio 2019 and I m facing this issue. how can I solve it.**

``

[image]

``

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676993/how-do-i-change-my-iis-express-ssl-certificate-for-one-that-will-work-with-chrom  or switch to using a local IIS installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Simply Click on Yes Button.
You will Get SSL Certificate to Run the Program on Browser.
Please try it and Tell me if you get any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer its very helpful for  me to solve this issue