# How can I specify SSL certificate when running appcmd add site?

Tags: iis, windows-10, ssl-certificate, appcmd

I can create a web site in IIS using e.g. the following command:

```
appcmd add site
  -name:portallocal
  -physicalPath:"C:\dev\projects\mysite"
  -bindings:https/127.0.0.1:444:mysite.dev
```

But how can I also select an SSL certificate?

I'd like the highlighted dropdown shown below to already have the correct SSL certificate selected, and I'd like to do it from the command-line, preferably as part of the add site command. if there's an additional command I can run, that's fine too, but I want to not have to go into the IIS Manager application and select the SSL certificate manually.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do figure it out. Seems one needs to use a different command:

```
netsh http add sslcert
  hostnameport=mysite.dev:444
  certhash=<hash/fingerprint of certificate>
  certstorename=my
  appid={f66e756c-145d-48c0-84d5-91a6a8e1900e}
```

What really confused me here, was the `appid`, as the app id for my site was `1`, but here there's a guid, and I couldn't figure out where to find the guid of my web site. Turns out, this guid, is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537226/39321) one you just make up yourself...

Comment: No, you are not supposed to make up an appid. Different apps (IIS Express/IIS) use their own ID so you should use your own as well if that’s your goal.

Comment: @LexLi What do you mean? What is "my goal" here? And what's "my own", where do I find that?