# "The parameter is incorrect" error using "netsh http add sslcert" on Windows Server 2022

Tags: ssl, iis, netsh, certutil, windows-server-2022

I have an "The parameter is incorrect." error on Windows Server 2022

I obtain the appid from `certutil -store "MY" %SSL_DOMAIN% ^| find "Key Container"`

Cert Hash(sha1): 6d5b92e25d056dc1c6dc671672e0dd2363ea1aac
**Key Container = !002a.fz-win.tk-2a270cf2-6652-4e79-81ce-36087def3cc2**
Provider = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider

And then use this "Key Container" value to set appid parameter

`netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=xxxxxx:443 certstorename=MY certhash=6d5b92e25d056dc1c6dc671672e0dd2363ea1aac appid=!002a.fz-win.tk-f2ee0730-9396-4a0a-8fdb-d62e126a753a`

The appid format is wrong and I think that the problem is with the provider on certutil.

These commands are for associate SSL certificate to binding.
These commands in legacy windows server work fine.
Please can you help me .

These commands are to associate SSL certificate to binding.

Comment: The `appid` field should be a unique GUID you generate on your own to identify your own HTTP application (who hooks to Windows HTTP API and handles incoming requests). That should never come from another place like the Key Container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[appid=GUID]**  Specifies the GUID to identify the owning application.

1. You need to specify an "appId", which is a Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) or Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) that Windows will use to identify the certificate.
2. If you have Visual Studio, you can use Tools -> Create GUID -> Choose "4. Registry Format".
3. There is a "free" GUID generator online https://guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx.
4. Or create your own: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

The command will look like this, just as an example:

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=xxxxxx:443 certstorename=MY certhash=6d5b92e25d056dc1c6dc671672e0dd2363ea1aac appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

Related reference links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert

https://superuser.com/questions/1094209/appid-or-guid-of-a-running-service

[What 'appid' should I use with netsh.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537173/what-appid-should-i-use-with-netsh-exe)